# Log Plot taking unusually long time

Tags: plotting

I am trying to run the following code

```
Ntrunc = 200 
    b[n_?IntegerQ, m_?IntegerQ, t_] := 
  1/2*Sum[x[[n, k]]*
     x[[k, m]]*((Energies[[k]] - Energies[[m]]) Exp[
         I*(Energies[[n]] - Energies[[k]])*t] - (Energies[[n]] - 
          Energies[[k]]) Exp[
         I*(Energies[[k]] - Energies[[m]])*t]), {k, 1, Ntrunc/2}];
MICROTOC[n_?IntegerQ, t_] := 
  Re[Sum[b[n, m, t]*Conjugate[b[n, m, t]], {m, 1, Ntrunc/2}]];
Z[T_] := Sum[Exp[-Energies[[n]]/T], {n, 1, Ntrunc/2}];

OTOC[T_, t_] := 
  Re[Sum[Exp[-Energies[[n]]/T]*MICROTOC[n, t], {n, 1, Ntrunc/2}]/
   Z[T]]; (*define the OTOC*)
LogPlot[{MICROTOC[1, t], MICROTOC[10, t], MICROTOC[40, t], 
  MICROTOC[100, t] }, {t, 0, 3},  
 PlotLabels -> {"n=1", "n=10", "n=40", "n=100"}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 5]
LogPlot[{OTOC[1, t], OTOC[40, t], OTOC[100, t], OTOC[200, t], 
  OTOC[400, t]}, {t, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLabel -> {"T=1", "T=40", "T=100", "T=200", "T=400"}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

where

```
x[m][n]
```

is an `Ntrunc/2` by `Ntrunc/2` sparse matrix.

```
Energies[k]
```

is an array with `Ntrunc` elements. The first LogPlot with `MICROTOC`  plots the graphs in a few minutes. However, the second group of`OTOC` graphs don't plot even after I wait for hours. I wonder if there's anything wrong with the code. The entire file is given [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aQtemYiUVPnlcjpAvJ1EQEMQmTbwFe7i/view?usp=sharing) for reference.

**EDIT:**

I am including here how Energies[] came about:

```
Ntrunc = 200; (*number of energy levels and wavefunctions we will use*)

EnergyLevels = 
 SortBy[Flatten[
   Table[{Pi*(N[BesselJZero[k, l]])^2, 
     1/(Pi*BesselJ[k + 1, N[BesselJZero[k, l]]])*
      BesselJ[k, Sqrt[Pi]*N[BesselJZero[k, l]]*r]*
      Exp[-I*k*[Theta]]}, {k, 0, Ntrunc}, {l, 1, Ntrunc}], 1], First]


EigenFunctions = 
 Take[Map[#[[2]] &, EnergyLevels], 
  Ntrunc] (*These are the first 200 wavefunctions, arranged in order 
of increasing energy.*)


Energies = 
 Take[Map[First, EnergyLevels], 
  Ntrunc] (*The first 200 energy levels of the circular billiard*) 


x = Table[
  NIntegrate[
   Integrate[
    r^2*Cos[[Theta]]*Conjugate[EigenFunctions[[m]]]* 
     EigenFunctions[[n]], {[Theta], 0, 2*[Pi]}], {r, 0, 1/
    Sqrt[Pi]}], {m, 1, Ntrunc/2}, {n, 1, Ntrunc/
   2}](*define the matrix xmn*)
```

Comment: Please include the definition for`Energies`.

Comment: I have added the definitions for energies and x. @Syed